# Error message; [IP]in-addr.arpa has no PTR record:

Tags: networking, ssh, dns, hostname

I'm trying to figure out how to find the hostnames of computers on the LAN network. I put in the known address of a computer, but I'm getting an error I don't understand.

```
michaelsavich@noranetserver:~$ host 10.1.10.10
10.10.1.10.in-addr.arpa has no PTR record
```

Both computers are on the same LAN, so the issue isn't with port forwarding or anything. For the record, the computer I ran host on was running Ubuntu Server 14.04 LTS, and 10.1.10.10 should belong to a MacBook.

Comment: This is not possible as far as I know unless you have set up a local nameserver for your network.

Comment: A nameserver, huh? What should I look into to go about implementing that?

Comment: Look up Dnsmasq - it runs on a server usually. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Dnsmasq

Comment: But wait a second. All I really want to do is see the names of the computers, like in the network pane on OSX/Windows. I can see the names from my Macbook in the Finder GUI, but I want to be able to replicate that behavior on Ubuntu Server.

Answer (score 1):

I would use nmap to do ping scanning (as root) e.g.

```
sudo nmap -sP 192.168.1.*
```

If nmap is not installed, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo apt-get install nmap
```

Comment: `sudo nmap -sP 192.168.1.0/24` or another netmask also works.  But this solution only works if PTR records are set up in a nameserver (which the lookup error shows is not the case).

Answer (score 0):

I think if you are not using dynamic dns , you should write the name of the PC manually in `/etc/bind/db.192` which is the reverse , then you can try `host` or `dig` tool .

This would help you to configure dns : [Site](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/dns-configuration.html)

Answer (score -1):

How about try to listing all out first, in terminal:

```
arp -a
```

from that, maybe you can figure out which names is which.
Hope this can help too.
([How to find a computer name in a LAN from the IP address?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126467/how-to-find-a-computer-name-in-a-lan-from-the-ip-address))

Comment: Sample of output:
? (10.1.10.28) at e4:ce:8f:27:25:c8 [ether] on eth1
? (10.1.10.101) at b8:8d:12:29:77:9a [ether] on eth1

Comment: Won't work if systems aren't in DNS.